# Troubleshooting Backend Unresponsiveness and 500 Error on Web Host in ASP.NET Core Application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, middleware

I'm currently facing a perplexing issue with my ASP.NET Core 6 web application when hosted on a web server. Everything functions flawlessly on my local development server, but once the application is deployed to the web host, I encounter a persistent problem with the backend.

Specifically, when I make requests to a test controller, there is no response from the backend, and I consistently receive a 500 Internal Server Error. The front-end components of the application appear to be working as expected, but the issue seems to be isolated to the backend.

Here are some key points about my setup:

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 as the backend framework.
The front-end of the application is developed using React.
The web host environment and my local development environment are configured similarly, which might be contributing to the problem.
I've already gone through the usual troubleshooting steps, including checking for misconfigured middleware, verifying the correct order of service registrations, and confirming that the web host environment supports ASP.NET Core 6 and React applications.

When I deploy the basic WeatherForecast project, it works perfectly on the web host. I don't know what I added that caused these issues.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause. I'm eager to receive guidance and insights from the community to help me diagnose and resolve this perplexing problem. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my startup.cs:

```
using EduGameTown.Classes;
using EduGameTown.Contexts;
using EduGameTown.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(opt => opt.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("EduGameTown"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(configuration.GetConnectionString("EduGameTown"))));


// CORS
builder.Services.AddCors();

// Authentication and Authorization
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();


// Dependency Injection
builder.Services.AddSingleton<JwtService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserRepository>();

// MVC and API Services
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));


var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    //app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(options => options
    .WithOrigins(new[] { "https://192.168.0.217:44460", "https://localhost:44460", "https://new.edugametown.com" })
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
    );

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

And here is my proxy middleware file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:40156';

const context = [
  "/swagger",
   "/api",
];

module.exports = function(app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

Comment: I suggest you could firstly enable the stdlogs inside the web.config if you host it inside the IIS. If you not host on the IIS, I suggest you could try to use dotnet run or directly click the exe to run the server application. Then you could try to send request to the server to reproduce the issue. It will generate the error logs inside the console or stdlogs, we need these logs and then we could know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue.

As the database was on a different server, the firewall of the other server had blocked the connection so the whole backend wouldnt run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).